# How React websites are indexed by search engines?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React (JS) builds the user interface on client side using JavaScript. I am just starting with it and wondering if there are any issues with indexing React apps from search engines perspective.

The client is getting only a small piece of html code and all the contents is generated on client side. Below is example of the source code that the client receives:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Are there any cons of using the React interface in terms of the indexing by search engines like Google? That was a huge disadvantage of using ajax. Should I take that into account? If not, then how for example Google can handle it?

Comment: I recommend to test it yourself to know the answer, Google provides test tools for that - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en - You could read blog post which have done similar research - e.g. https://www.andrewhfarmer.com/react-seo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web crawlers will only be able to see whatever content is there in your html page. It would not know about the data that is send by react or basically it does not crawl the javascript part of your code. You will have to use server side rendering for web crawlers to see the content of your page. Server side rendering means, react pre-renders the html content of the first page on the server itself so the page that is send would contain the content of the page.

[This page](https://www.andrewhfarmer.com/server-side-render/) talks about server side rendering, its pros and cons